# data binding xml to gridview, fine but then doesnt display in webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, data-binding, aspxgridview

I am having issues displaying my gridview that is pulling information from an .xml file. 
There are no errors, it just isn't displaying on the web page (index.aspx).

I have finally gotten my code to the point where it isnt throwing an error, but now it doesnt display on the webpage at all.

I need to create an attractive index.aspx but I just need this linked first!

As soon as I can get this linked, I can move onto my following pages, css etc.

Here is index.aspx:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="purchaseGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRegistrations_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("id")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRegistrations_FullName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("fullName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Email" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("emailAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("productname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_UP" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("unitprice") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </asp:TemplateField>

               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_quantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>

</body>
```

Here is my csharp:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;



public class purchases : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/purchases.xml"));
        purchaseGrid.DataSource = ds;
        purchaseGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here is my xml doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <purchases>
        <Purchase>
            <id>1</id>
            <fullName>Keiran Bernal</fullName>
            <emailAddress>k.bernal@gmail.com</emailAddress>
            <productname>Lab created engagement ring</productname>
            <unitprice>5000</unitprice>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
        </Purchase>
        <Purchase>
            <id>2</id>
            <fullName>Zachery Guy</fullName>
            <emailAddress>z.guy@yahoo.com</emailAddress>
            <productname>"flowergirl" necklace</productname>
            <unitprice>1000</unitprice>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
        </Purchase>
        <Purchase>
            <id>3</id>
            <fullName>Cordelia Pierce</fullName>
            <emailAddress>c.pierce@outlook.com</emailAddress>
            <productname>Semi-precious gem ring</productname>
            <unitprice>500</unitprice>
            <quantity>2</quantity>
        </Purchase>
        <Purchase>
            <id>4</id>
            <fullName>Kiana Hawworth</fullName>
            <emailAddress>k.hawworth@bigpond.com</emailAddress>
            <productname>Pearl Earrings</productname>
            <unitprice>250</unitprice>
            <quantity>15</quantity>
        </Purchase>
    </purchases>
```

Comment: Tested your code and xml. It works fine. (but you do have an extra `</asp:TemplateField>` in the GridView at Unit Price)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the extra  from the unit price template. It will break the HTML structure.